# How to fill a vector of lists?

Tags: c++, list, vector

I'm trying to put ascii codes and names into a vector of lists: So ideally what it would be like is this:

**97:** "awesome", "all"

**98:** "best" , "boom", "bomb"

**99:** "cat"

I have

```
class index_table
{
public:
   index_table() { table.resize(128);}
   void insert(string &, int);
private:
   class entry {           //Subclass
      string word;
      vector <int> line;
    }
   vector< list <entry > > table;
```

So how can I correctly put these words and ascii number into the vector of lists?

In main I've tried some syntax, but it's not working:

```
void index_table :: insert ( string & word, int num) //This is the code for "cat" and "99"
{
    entry obj;
    //This is the part I'm not sure about. How do I enter each word and num into the vector < list < entry >> table

}
```

Hopefully I made this clear enough. To sum up, I'm confused on how a vector < list < entry > > table works. Or rather, how will I be able to store my number and words in it correctly?

Comment: Why not simply `std::map<int, std::vector<std::string> >` ?

Comment: @P0W: I believe that the reason for key -> entry, where entry contains word + line numbers is because he's working on some kind of search index.

Comment: @LihO idk, but `vector<int>` for `line` doesn't make sense with given example

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for data structure to hold the following:
ID ~> list of `entry` objects
ID ~> another list...

Yet the following type of `table` was wrong decision:

```
vector< list <entry > > table;
```

In case those numbers are unique indeed, it would be much wiser to use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
std::map<int, std::list<entry> > table;
```

or in C++11 even [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: They are unique. So, how would I call the vector < list < entry > > table then?